# sql insert procedure isnt working

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

```
CREATE PROCEDURE band
@band_id NUMBER(8,2)  = NULL,
@band_name VARCHAR(15)  = NULL ,
@band_size NUMBER (8,2)  = NULL ,
@band_genre VARCHAR(15) = NULL ,
@number_of_songs NUMBER (8,2)  = NULL,

@average_song_time VARCHAR(15) = NULL ,
@festival_id NUMBER(8,2)  = NULL,
@stage_id NUMBER(8,2)  = NULL 


AS

BEGIN

INSERT INTO band
(band_id,

band_name,

band_size,

band_genre,

number_of_songs,

average_song_time)

VALUES (@band_id,
    @band_name,
    @band_size,
    @band_genre,
    @number_of_songs,
    @average_song_time)

END
```

sql insert procedure isnt working "success, but compilation error"

wanting to implement a procedure that will allow the user to insert their own data into the "band" table on the forms page on application builder

Comment: You must include your code in your question: indent by four spaces to make a code block.

Comment: what exactly goes wrong? "isn't working" could mean anything.

Comment: I haven't spotted any error in the code. The error message doesn't seem to be database related at all, so it's likely that the error is somewhere else. Check the entire error message for any clues to where it comes from.

Comment: thanks for the reply ill have a check

Answer (score 0):

1. As noted in the [MSDN documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187926(v=sql.105).aspx), you are not able to name a stored procedure the same as an already existing object in that schema.

> Procedure names must comply with the rules for identifiers and must be unique within the schema.

2. If you change the [datatype](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-types-transact-sql) NUMBER to NUMERIC this stored procedure will work, however depending on your design requirements you may wish to explore other number datatypes.

   ```
   CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[p_band]

   @band_id numeric(8,2) = NULL,
   @band_name VARCHAR(15) = NULL,
   @band_size numeric (8,2) = NULL,
   @band_genre VARCHAR(15) = NULL,
   @number_of_songs numeric(8,2) = NULL,
   @average_song_time VARCHAR(15) = NULL ,
   @festival_id numeric(8,2) = NULL,
   @stage_id numeric(8,2) = NULL 

   AS

   BEGIN

   INSERT INTO band
   (
    band_id,
    band_name,
    band_size,
    band_genre,
    number_of_songs,
    average_song_time
    )

   VALUES 
   (
    @band_id,
    @band_name,
    @band_size,
    @band_genre,
    @number_of_songs,
    @average_song_time
    )

   END
   ```

Answer (score -3):

First Change Name Of Your Proc

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE Insertband
 @band_id NUMBER(8,2)  = NULL,
 @band_name VARCHAR(15)  = NULL ,
 @band_size NUMBER (8,2)  = NULL ,
 @band_genre VARCHAR(15) = NULL ,
 @number_of_songs NUMBER (8,2)  = NULL,

@average_song_time VARCHAR(15) = NULL ,
 @festival_id NUMBER(8,2)  = NULL,
@stage_id NUMBER(8,2)  = NULL 
AS

BEGIN

INSERT INTO band
(band_id,

band_name,

band_size,

band_genre,

number_of_songs,

 average_song_time)

VALUES (@band_id,
@band_name,
@band_size,
@band_genre,
@number_of_songs,
@average_song_time)

END
```

This will work

Comment: it would be better to explain _why_ this change will help.

Comment: This suggestion does not improve the code nor fix any known problem. -1